# Set some styles if an element is followed by an element with same attribute

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

Suppose

```html
<div myattr='user1'>abcd</div>
<div myattr='user2'>1234</div>
<div myattr='user2'>wxyz</div>
<div myattr='user3'>7890</div>
```

For now third element's display must be none.

I tried

```css
div[myattr='user2'] ~ div[myattr='user2'] {
    display: none;
}
```

But this code only works for element whose `myattr` is `user2` not for other users / attribute values and this sets display of third element to none instead of second.

I want to set some styles to every element whose next element have same attribute.

How can I achieve this?

CSS code is preferred but JavaScript can also work here.

Comment: What if you have three in a row? Are both of the second two hidden?

Comment: if i have first second and third element from above example second element should have none display. if i have first second and fourth element none of them should have none displlay

Comment: I don't understand how that answers my question. If you have `<div myattr="a">1</div><div myattr="a">2</div><div myattr="a">3</div>`, do you want 3 hidden or not?

Comment: for your example i want first and second element to be hidden but not the third one

Comment: can css do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to refer back to the earlier element's attribute value, I don't think you can do this with CSS. It's fairly straightforward with JavaScript:

```
for (const entry of document.querySelectorAll("[data-myattr]")) {
    const next = entry.nextElementSibling;
    if (next.getAttribute("data-myattr") === entry.getAttribute("data-myattr")) {
        entry.classList.add("hidden");
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const display = document.getElementById("display");
display.textContent = "Before";
setTimeout(() => {
    for (const entry of document.querySelectorAll("[data-myattr]")) {
        const next = entry.nextElementSibling;
        if (next.getAttribute("data-myattr") === entry.getAttribute("data-myattr")) {
            entry.classList.add("hidden");
        }
    }
    display.textContent = "After";
}, 1000);
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
<hr>
<div data-myattr='user1'>first user1</div>
<div data-myattr='user2'>first user2</div>
<div data-myattr='user2'>second user2</div>
<div data-myattr='user3'>first user3</div>
<hr>
<div data-myattr='user1'>first user1</div>
<div data-myattr='user2'>first user2</div>
<div data-myattr='user3'>first user3</div>
<div data-myattr='user3'>second user3</div>
<div data-myattr='user3'>third user3</div>
<hr>
<div data-myattr='user1'>first user1</div>
<div data-myattr='user2'>first user2</div>
<div data-myattr='user3'>first user3</div>
<div data-myattr='user2'>second user2 but not in a row</div>
<div data-myattr='user3'>second user3 but not in a row</div>
```

---

Side note: I've used `data-myattr` rather than `myattr` above because [custom attributes should always use the `data-` prefix](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: My original answer hid the wrong element. I've updated to hide the *earlier* one, not the later one.